# Updating users_can_register option?

Tags: functions, options

I have a custom setting page, where i have a radio to Enable or Disable Registration then try to update the wpoption (users_can_register). 
Screenshot:[image]

I've tried both true/false & 1/0 but it doesnt update when i saved it in my custom settings, but when i checked the checkbox in the general settings, it gets updated..

Here's the codes im trying to use on my theme's functions.php

```
if (get_option('user-reg-allow') == 'enable') {
    update_option('users_can_register',1);
}
elseif (get_option('user-reg-allow') == 'disable') {
    update_option('users_can_register',0);
}
```

Comment: Are the option names different - the first one looks like a typo?

Comment: @Welcher oops, my bad. Yes a typo xD

Comment: Where is this code being processed? I think we might need some more context to be able to help

Comment: I placed it on my theme's function.php also the radio enable/disable on the framework acera.